# parse an HTML line for inner text

Tags: c#, html, xml

I am trying to parse an html document by **td** tags using C#
so that

```
<td>Whatever string</td><td class="pass">value</td>
```

would return

```
Whatever string : value
```

I have spent hours on this problem, trying XML parsers, and regular expressions, but to no avail.  Thanks for your help.

I have already tried

```
    List<string> list = Regex.Split(lineslineWithTdTag[i], "[<td>].[<\td>]").ToList();
    List<string> status = Regex.Split(list[3], "[pass=\"].\"").ToList() ;
```

and then I tried parsing that list

Comment: You need to show whatever code you have tried.

Comment: What have you tried?  If you post the code you're using we can help work out the problem.

Comment: Have you tried the HtmlAgilityPack?

Comment: You can't parse HTML with regex, you can't parse HTML with XMLParser (because it may not be valid XML unless it's XHTML). You need a raw HTML parser: flag is 0? - save name - set flag to 1, flag is 1? save value - set flag to 0

Comment: HTML, though similar, is not XML so using a XML parser would not work. In regards to regex, I feel it's obligatory to link this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 HtmlAgilityPack is almost *always* the go-to solution for this kind of problem. Have you looked into that?

Comment: html document should contain root node. Where you get these elements from?

Comment: I have looked into HtmlAgilityPack, however due to restrictions at work I am unable to download any external libraries.

Comment: You really need to read the Regex documentation.  Your syntax is all wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of incurring the wrath of the "you can't parse HTML with Regex" purists, here's a regex solution that should do what you want:

```
var match = Regex.Match(lineslineWithTdTag[I], "<td>(.*?)</td><td.*?>(.*?)</td>");
string result = String.Format(match.Groups[1].Value + " : " + match.Groups[2].Value);
```

Of course, if the actual documented is not as well formatted as your example then all bets are off.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454

Comment: @icemanind - Yes, I saw that in the comments above, and love the answer.  I agree that Regex cannot be used to parse HTML in general.  However, for a subset of possible HTML cases, where the HTML is formatted predictably, it can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of work, this ended up being my solution

```
        string path = @"http://localhost/page.html";
        XDocument myX = XDocument.Load(path);
        string field1 = "";
        string field2 = "";
        bool flag = true;
        foreach (var name in myX.Root.DescendantNodes().OfType<XElement>())
        {
            // get the first element
            if (name.Name.LocalName == "td" && flag)
            {
                field1 = (string)name + "\n";
                flag = false;
            }
            // get the second element
            else if (name.Name.LocalName == "td")
            {
                field2 = (string)name + "\n";
                flag = true;
            }
        }
    }
```